# Quicksort C - contest.c:16:50: error: request for member ‘nome’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct, quicksort

Estou tentando fazer essa questão do URI:

> Tetris
>
> A sua turma do colégio resolveu organizar um campeonato de tetris.
>   Após discussão sobre as regras, ficou definido que cada aluno jogaria
>   um total de 12 partidas. Das 12 pontuações obtidas por um aluno, a
>   maior e a menor são descartadas, e as demais são somadas, resultando
>   na pontuação final do aluno.
>
> Como você possui conhecimentos de programação, acabou sendo designado
>   pela turma para escrever um programa para imprimir a classificação
>   final do campeonato, a partir das pontuações de cada jogador. Entrada
>
> A entrada é composta de vários conjuntos de teste. A primeira linha de
>   um conjunto de testes contém um número inteiro J (0 ≤ J ≤ 1000), que
>   indica o número de jogadores que participaram do campeonato. A seguir,
>   para cada jogador há duas linhas na entrada: a primeira possui o nome
>   do jogador (formado apenas por letras, sendo apenas a inicial em
>   maiúscula, e com no máximo 15 letras), e a segunda possui as 12
>   pontuações que o jogador obteve, separadas por espaço. As pontuações
>   são inteiros entre 0 e 1000. O final da entrada é indicado por um
>   conjunto de teste com J = 0. Saída
>
> Para cada conjunto de teste, o seu programa deve escrever uma linha
>   contendo o identificador do conjunto de teste, no formato “Teste n”,
>   onde n é numerado seqüencialmente a partir de 1. A seguir, o seu
>   programa deve escrever a classificação final no campeonato, utilizando
>   uma linha para cada participante. Cada linha deve conter três
>   informações, separadas por um espaço em branco: a classificação do
>   jogador, a sua pontuação final, e o seu nome. A classificação de um
>   jogador é igual a 1 mais o número de jogadores que obtiveram pontuação
>   maior do que a sua. Em caso de empate, os jogadores devem ser
>   ordenados em ordem alfabética. Depois de toda a classificação, deve
>   ser deixada uma linha em branco. O formato do exemplo de saída abaixo
>   deve ser seguido rigorosamente.

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2250

Estou na parte de organizar por ordem alfabética os que têm a mesma quantidade de pontos. Tentei fazer uma condição no quicksort pra quando os pontos forem iguais, ordenar por nome e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> contest.c: In function ‘compare’: contest.c:16:30: error: request for
>   member ‘nome’ in something not a structure or union    return
>   strcmp(((Jogador*)a).nome, ((Jogador*)b).nome);
>                                 ^ contest.c:16:50: error: request for member ‘nome’ in something not a structure or union    return
>   strcmp(((Jogador*)a).nome, ((Jogador*)b).nome);

Alguém pode me explicar o que é? "Aprendi" isso hoje e to meio que fazendo às cegas. O meu código é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char nome[16];
    int pontuacao;
}Jogador;

int compare(const void * a, const void * b){
    if((*(Jogador *)a).pontuacao > (*(Jogador *)b).pontuacao){
        return -1;
    }else if((*(Jogador *)a).pontuacao < (*(Jogador *)b).pontuacao){
        return 1;
    }else if((*(Jogador *)a).pontuacao == (*(Jogador *)b).pontuacao){
        return strcmp(((Jogador*)a).nome, ((Jogador*)b).nome);
    }

    return 0;
}

int achaMaior(int *pontos){
    int maior = pontos[0];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1; i < 12; i++){
        if(pontos[i] > maior){
            maior = pontos[i];
        }
    }

    return maior;
}

int achaMenor(int *pontos){
    int menor = pontos[0];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1; i < 12; i++){
        if(pontos[i] < menor){
            menor = pontos[i];
        }
    }

    return menor;
}

Jogador jogador[100];

int main(){
    int j, i, k , pontos[12], maior, menor, teste = 0;;

    scanf("%d", &j);

    while(j != 0){
        teste++;
        for(i = 0; i < j; i++){
            scanf("%s", jogador[i].nome);
            for(k = 0; k < 12; k++){
                scanf("%d", &pontos[k]);
                jogador[i].pontuacao += pontos[k];
            }

            maior = achaMaior(pontos);
            menor = achaMenor(pontos);

            jogador[i].pontuacao -= (maior + menor);
        }

        qsort(jogador, j, sizeof(jogador[0]), compare);

        printf("Teste %d\n", teste);
        for(i = 0; i < j; i++){
            printf("%d %d %s\n", i + 1, jogador[i].pontuacao, jogador[i].nome);
        }

        printf("\n");

        for(i = 0; i < j; i++){
            jogador[i].pontuacao = 0;
        }

        scanf("%d", &j);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver isso. Estava faltando um ponteiro na seguinte linha:

```
return strcmp(((Jogador*)a).nome, ((Jogador*)b).nome);
```

Linha corrigida:

```
return strcmp((*(Jogador*)a).nome, (*(Jogador*)b).nome);
```